# Как сделать поиск mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

У меня есть столбец 'region'
В нем записаны: Москва, Санкт-Петербург, Омск, Сочи, Пермь... и тд.
Знаю обычный поиск выглядит так:"SELECT * FROM `objects` WHERE `region` LIKE 'Москва';"
Как мне сделать поиск где регион не только Москва но и Санкт-Петербург, Омск, Сочи и тд ???

Comment: [SELECT * FROM objects
WHERE region IN ('Москва', 'Санкт-Петербург', 'Омск');](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"SELECT * FROM objects WHERE region LIKE '%Москва%' OR region  LIKE '%Омск%' OR region LIKE '%сочи%'"